# Unit and co-unit of Exponential Product and Sets

Tags: category-theory

Let $\cal C$ be a category with binary products and let $Y$ and $Z$ be objects of $\cal C$. The exponential object $Z^Y$ can be defined as a universal morphism from the functor $–×Y$ to $Z$.

> **Adjunction Between Exponential and Product**
>
> $(-)×X \dashv (-)^X$

I need help describing the unit and co-unit for these adjoint functors.

Can someone help me describe them please?

Comment: Describe them in terms of what? $\mathcal{C}$ could be a completely abstract category here.

Comment: The counit $ε$ at $Z$ is simply the universal morphism $Z^Y\times Y\to Z$ you started with. The unit is the unique arrow $\eta_X:X\to (X×Y)^Y$ such that $ε_{X×Y}(\eta_X\times 1_Y)=1_{X\times Y}$, whose existence follows from the universality of $ε$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Professor Awodey describes the counit of this adjunction as evaluation -- does the unit also have a simple name? Is it related to representable functors perhaps? https://youtu.be/8fZmdhLLgs4?t=45m20s

Comment: the same is found in JOHNSTONE's topos theory , section 1. 3